# Crontab empty but using excessive CPU

Tags: cron

I screwed up making a simple crontab entry and now crontab is using 6% of my CPU and I dont know how to fix it.

I added to `crontab -e`

```
0 6 * * * pkill caffeine && caffeine && notify-send "Killed caffeine"
```

But now when I look in crontab -e there is nothing there yet crontab is using lots of CPU.

How can I fix this, and what did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you know crontab is using a lot of CPU? Is a process named `crontab` actually using that much CPU? Not `crond`?

Comment: @KeithThompson According to `gnome-system-monitor`, it was actually called `crontab`.

Comment: I killed crontab and that solved the CPU problem for now...

Comment: That's odd. `crontab` is just the program that lets you update your crontab. It doesn't run the commands, just queries and updates the system information.